# How to set Site Speed Sample Rate property in GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Site Speed Sample Rate can be set in create method in GA. But I pushed my events through GTM not directly to GA.
So, Is there any options on GTM to set the container property or how to set it??

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/ncKHa4Mg_Qg